# OpenCV: estimateAffine3D throws a hard-to-decipher exception

Tags: c++, opencv, affinetransform

I am using OpenCV to record pointclouds from Kinect and other cameras. To sync the pointclouds together, I want to use a 3D calibration rig and cv::estimateAffine3D(). However, OpenCV throws this strange exception at me when I try to use the function:

```
OpenCV Exception: C:\Tools\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:1466: 
error: (-215) mtype == type0 || (CV_MAT_CN(mtype) == CV_MAT_CN(type0) && 
((1 << type0) & fixedDepthMask) != 0)
```

I cannot figure out what the exception text wants to tell me and Google gives no relevant results, maybe someone else knows more than me on that matter. Thank you!

EDIT: This is my call to the function:

```
cv::Mat affine;

std::vector<cv::Point> inliers;

cv::estimateAffine3D(camPoints,objPoints,affine,inliers,5.0,0.96);
```

where both camPoints and objPoints are `std::vector<cv::Point3f>` types, camPoints being the corners that findChessboardCorners returns (reprojected to 3D camera space) and objPoints simply a vector denoting the same corners in object space, in this case it's contents look like this:
(0,0,0),(40,0,0),(80,0,0),...,(0,40,0),(40,40,0),(80,40,0)...(0,200,0),(40,200,0),(80,200,0)

Comment: This indicates a problem with the supplied parameters, most likely one of the OutputArrays. Can you please show your code (the call to cv::estimateAffine3D including all used variables).

Comment: Yes, I edited the question with that information.

Comment: I think the "inliers" are not reported as points but as their respective indices, so you should try `std::vector<unsigned char> inliers;` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives the same results. :/ I tried unsigned char and unsigned int.

Comment: Ah, your input parameters are supposed to be sets of 3D points, not 2D as it seems from your description.

Comment: Yea, sorry, I am very confused right now. I forgot the third coordinate there... Edited again.

Comment: Okay, I figured this out: Apparently, the function that gave me the reprojected chessboard corners was faulty (but worked fine before). Apparently, this exception want to say that something is not quite right with the input points, in my case all the `camPoints` were (0,0,0). 
Thanks for helping out, Niko!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the function that gave me the reprojected chessboard corners was faulty (but worked fine before). Apparently, this exception want to say that something is not quite right with the input points, in my case all the camPoints were (0,0,0).